# chrome/jquery ajax timeout reissued

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have a code that runs jquery ajax, I'm using this code for 2 years with no problem, but lately it seems that chrome seems to restart the request if it didn't finish after ~10 minutes.

I solve it by creating a tmp lock file, but I wonder what is the cause of this issue, I assume it is a new chrome version, but I couldn't find any documentation to this.

Is there some documentation for jQuery or chrome that suggest that AJAX request is reissued on a time out?

Comment: just out of curiosity, what type of request is taking more than 10 minutes?

Comment: It's an internal code that run a kind of a crawler